# What does "a voice that is bright red" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have come across the following passage. I just cannot figure out what "a voice that is bright red" means although I have checked my dictionaries.

> I’ve become so attached to my phone
> that the sun no longer provides light.
> I’ve become so attached to my phone
> that I don’t know how to talk to my best friend
> face to face.
> It’s hard to socialize in person
> but behind a screen I am powerful.
> **I have a voice that is bright red**
> that can scream at these
> stupid blue screens.
>
> I’ve become so attached
> that it is starting to feel like I’ve become addicted.
> I’m always on social media.
> Constantly texting, liking, commenting.
>
> There are days I cry, stressing about
> how many followers I have
> and how many likes I receive.
> It’s like a job, keeping the data of
> every single notification sent to me.
> I’m lost behind this stupid blue screen.
>
> I’m done with these stupid blue screens.
> They don’t let me think.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Please tell us where this passage is from.

Comment: It's a poem https://826digital.com/writing/stupid-blue-screen/

Answer (score 2):

This is a [poem](https://826digital.com/writing/stupid-blue-screen/) and poets tend to use more figurative language.

There isn't any idiomatic meaning of "my voice is bright red".  In context it seems to suggest that her voice is high pitched, and angry.  Perhaps she doesn't like the sound of her voice or is self-conscious about it, which is partly why she finds it hard to talk face-to-face.